# How to disable encoding of selenium undetected driver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumwire, undetected-chromedriver

I am having trouble adding the option "disable_encoding" to the seleniumwire undetected chromedriver

My code right now is as follows:

```
# Configure chrome options
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.user_data_dir = "/Users/me/chrome"
options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
options.disable_encoding=True # This is what I ca't enable
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/servicelogin')
for request in driver.requests:
print(request.response.body)
```

Does someone know how I can configure the "disable_encoding" to stop receiving http responses as bytes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
options = { "disable_encoding":True}
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
```